# How to manage a Spring-MVC web application in Eclipse with same workspace for different database testing

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-mvc

I am working on a Spring MVC project with running Tomcat server and using Eclipse STS IDE.

I need to test my project's functionality with different databases (SQL, oracle and postgreSQL database).

To test same functionality in all databases, every time I am changing `applicationProperies.properties` file to change database configuration and restarting the sever. Is there any way where I can test my application parallely with all databases?

Comment: Try to create the `profile` and configure it under the `configuration` class.